# handling multitouch events in libgdx (on android)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, multi-touch

Hey so I am using libgdx to develop a game and I am using an input multiplexer to handle the input for both touch and keyboard based input's here is the class with the relevant `@Overide` methods that I am currently implementing. ( i started with only handling keyboard events for easier rapid development and have now re-implemented to handle touch events as well) Anayways I have everything mapped out the way i wish however on touch device I cannot seem to properly implement multitouch ie. when I am moving left or right I can't also jump or throw a star I am not sure exactly why this is (I have read a bug with Galaxy Nexus and how it handles multitouch) however I am running Galaxy S3 & Galaxy tab3  and am haven't seen same accounts anywhere with theses devices. (and on desktop with keys i can run+ jum+ throwstar etc. )

Anyways here is the most relevant code below in the multiplexer / InputProccesor . If I have left any relevant information out please don't hesitate to ask and I can update with it.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen, GestureListener, InputProcessor{

    GestureDetector gestureDetector ;
    String message;
    int directionPointer, actionPointer;
  public GameScreen(Game game, int levelNum){

    controller = new BobController(world, this);
    InputMultiplexer im = new InputMultiplexer();
    GestureDetector gd = new GestureDetector(this);
    im.addProcessor(gd);
    im.addProcessor(this);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(im);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keys.LEFT)
        controller.leftPressed();
    if (keycode == Keys.RIGHT)
        controller.rightPressed();
    if (keycode == Keys.Z)
        controller.jumpPressed();
    if (keycode == Keys.C)
        controller.throwPressed();
    if (keycode == Keys.X)
        controller.punchPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    if (keycode == Keys.LEFT)
        controller.leftReleased();
    if (keycode == Keys.RIGHT)
        controller.rightReleased();
    if (keycode == Keys.Z)
        controller.jumpReleased();
    if (keycode == Keys.X)
        controller.punchReleased();
    if (keycode == Keys.C)
        controller.throwReleased();
    if (keycode == Keys.D)
        renderer.setDebug(!renderer.isDebug());
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    message= "keyTyped was detected";
    Gdx.app.log("INFO", message);
    return false;

}


/// all below methods are for touch based game play
@Override
public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    if(Math.abs(velocityX)>Math.abs(velocityY)){
        if(velocityX>0){
            controller.throwPressed();
            return true;
        }else{

        }
    }else{
        if(velocityY<0){
            controller.jumpPressed();
            return true;
        }else{   
            controller.punchPressed();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
    /*if (!Gdx.app.getType().equals(ApplicationType.Android))
        return false;*/
    if (x < width / 3 && y > height / 2) {
        directionPointer= pointer;
        if(x< width/6){     
            controller.leftPressed();
            return true;
        }else{
            controller.rightPressed();  
            return true;
        }       

    }else{
        actionPointer= pointer;

    }
    return false;

}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {

    if ( pointer==directionPointer) {           
        controller.leftReleased();
        controller.rightReleased(); 
        return true;                
    }
    return true;

}
}
```

Comment: How are you differentiating "moving left or right" from "throwing a star"?  Are those different regions of the screen (do you have something like a virtual joystick on screen)?  Or are you mapping different action (tap is move, swipe is throw)?  Or something else?

Comment: hey yes to detect move left or right finger must be on bottom right thirds of the screen , to detect jumps, throwstar or punch swipe motion must be made anywhere on sreen other then that bottom left third

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I have gotten to the bottom of why I can not detect a fling while another finger is on screen (in my case make the charecter move). The reason is that fling is not a multitouch enabled event as a result, it only is detect if only event being triggered by gesture detector. 
As a result I am currently reworking logic to use touchdown and pan , panstop events in order to proccess what would be a multitouch sensing of a fling. I will update with code on how I implemented this and some of the bugs it may cause. for anyone else who runs into same problem in future.